# startActivity unable to pass extra bundle to target activity everytime

Tags: android

Currently, I'm launching a target activity from my `AppWidgetProvider`

### Code for AppWidgetProvider

```
Intent newIntent = new Intent(context, TargetActivity.class);
newIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
newIntent.putExtra(INTENT_EXTRA_CLICKED_OPTIONS_MENU, R.id.menu_search);
context.startActivity(newIntent);
```

Every-time I perform launching, there are 2 possible flows in my `TargetActivity`

1. `onCreate` will be called, followed by `onResume`
2. Only `onResume` will be called.

I realize, when

### Only `onResume` will be called

I was not able to obtain extra bundle in `onResume`

```
// Code for TargetActivity
public void onResume() {
    Intent intent = this.getIntent();
    //
    // "extras" always null, if the flow is
    // Widget launch target activity -> target activity onResume
    //
    //
    // "extras" is not null, if the flow is
    // Widget launch target activity -> target activity onCreate -> target activity onResume
    //
    Bundle extras = intent.getExtras();
}
```

Is there any way I can ensure, when launching `TargetActivity`, I will always get a non null extra bundle?

Answer (score 0):

From [launchMode#singleTop](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html#lmode)

> The "standard" and "singleTop" modes differ from each other in just one respect: Every time there's a new intent for a "standard" activity, a new instance of the class is created to respond to that intent. Each instance handles a single intent. Similarly, a new instance of a "singleTop" activity may also be created to handle a new intent. **However, if the target task already has an existing instance of the activity at the top of its stack, that instance will receive the new intent (in an onNewIntent() call); a new instance is not created.**

From [onNewIntent()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onNewIntent(android.content.Intent))

> This is called for activities that set launchMode to "singleTop" in their package, or if a client used the FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP flag when calling startActivity(Intent). In either case, when the activity is re-launched while at the top of the activity stack instead of a new instance of the activity being started, onNewIntent() will be called on the existing instance with the Intent that was used to re-launch it.
>
> An activity will always be paused before receiving a new intent, so you can count on onResume() being called after this method.
>
> Note that getIntent() still returns the original Intent. You can use setIntent(Intent) to update it to this new Intent.

That said, I believe that implementing `onNewIntent` in your `TargetActivity` and setting the current intent with `setIntent()` will solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

`Activity` has a method called `onNewIntent()`:

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onNewIntent%28android.content.Intent%29

It gets called if the Activity had already been created and was later sent an Intent. It looks like that's what you're looking for.